# How to run cron automatically after node published?

Tags: cron

cron has to run after some time  of node publishing.I tried like this

```
 function custom_module_cron{
//($updated = node published time)
if(date("Y/m/d H:i:s") == date("Y/m/d H:i:s",$updated+60)){
//code here
}
}
```

but its not running automatically. Can anybody help ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need to do 60 seconds after a node is published?  cron is likely not the right solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you managed your cron configuration, if no then go to **/admin/config/system/cron** and set your cron settings to run on that interval of time.

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .But my requirement is not particular interval of time .after 60 seconds of every node publishing.